# PropTypes is deprecated and how to solve it

Tags: node.js, react-native

i am getting the error

> Undefined is not an object (Evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.string')

While googling I found out that `React.Proptypes` is deprecated and it's on its own.

But, How can I solve this issue ?

I tried the following:

1.) `npm install -g prop-types --save`

2.) part from the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { Container, Input, Button, Item, Spinner } from '../common';
import styles from './authStyle';

const propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  clearState: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  signUpUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  authError: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }
...
```

However, I end up having the same error and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  buttonStyle: PropTypes.object,
  textStyle: PropTypes.object,
};

const defaultProps = {
  buttonStyle: {},
  textStyle: {},
};

function Button({ onPress, children, buttonStyle, textStyle }) {
  const { button, text } = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={onPress}
      style={[button, buttonStyle]}
    >
      <Text style={[text, textStyle]}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = {
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#039be5',
    borderRadius: 3,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  text: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
};

Button.defaultProps = defaultProps;
Button.propTypes = propTypes;

export { Button };
```

Comment: This might take a while, but a sure-fire way to find this particular bug would be too log all of your variables and finding where the breakpoint is, that is, what's below the last loggable item.

Comment: Are there any other option except for downgrading react-native

Comment: Which component is causing this

Comment: You installed the package globally. try removing and then installing it locally. `npm uninstall -g prop-types --save && npm install prop-types --save`

Comment: It's also possible a library you're using in your project is using `React.PropTypes` and giving you warnings.

Comment: @bennygenel That did not work too. Anyway, I am planning to scrap up the project and start all over again.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Button.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: May I know why is this down voted. I am still learning, so would be nice if someone can let me know the reason as well.

Comment: You didn't give any context to your answer and it seems you just added the usage of `PropTypes`. It doesn't look any different then how did the OP use. Just code or just link answers considered as low quality in SO.